# Is "applied for a job with somebody" correct?

Tags: prepositions

I don't quite get what is wrong with this sentence but have a feeling that it is not correct:

> 'I've just applied **for** a job with you.'

Please let me know what is wrong. If it's grammatically correct, doesn't it sound weird? How would a native speaker say it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. It is informal, the kind of sentence that is much more likely to be spoken than written. A more formal version might read: *I have just applied for X position with your company....*

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence. it is grammatically correct.

I wonder if you want it to sound more professional? If so, how about:

**I have applied for a position with your firm.**

**I applied for the position of XXX,  with (name of company) on (date).**

The word *just*, doesn't sound professional. There is nothing wrong with it if you are applying for a job as a barista, but sounds less than ideal for the position of office worker.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker, it sounds grammatically correct to me. However, usage would depend on the situation.

If you run into a potential co-worker, I would say "Oh! I just applied for a position at your company/in your department" or "I recently applied to here" (if you are THERE at the moment).

I don't have any problem with *just* - *just* indicates very recently, to me it does not sound less formal or anything like that. I'm a librarian and I've used it in similar contexts.

I wouldn't, however, say "with you" because that's most likely not true. That is, you did not apply to work solely with that person - you applied to work at the company with everyone that works there. It sounds odd to single out one person like that. Unless, off course, you're talking to a close friend that works for A company and you say "I just applied to work with you!" - which would be taken in joking manner, mostly likely.